# Java Inheritance - members of parent & child

Tags: java, oop

```
public class Parent {
       int num = 10;

       public void method(){
           System.out.println("Parent method");
       }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    int num = 20;  // Why this declaration is allowed ?
     public void method(){
       System.out.println("Child method");
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Parent f = new Child();
        Child f2 = new Child();
        System.out.println(f.num);
        System.out.println(f2.num);
    }

}
```

Why same name variable declaration is allowed in child class.
According to inheritance, child should inherit parent properties.
Please explain.

Comment: Did you tried to read any book or online document by yourself ? And did you get anything which you got from those tutorials about this?

Comment: do `Child c = new Child()` and `Parent p = new Child()` and print the value of `num` .. You will get to know why:)

Comment: it allows to change values of  properties .for example every car has a body color but color is different.so if it's not allowed then every car has same color

Comment: Try to read from some book then ask ..

Answer (score 1):

> Why this declaration is allowed ?

Because the language allows to *override* methods and *hide* members  - in your case you're *hiding* the parents `num` member.

The `num` value for the child is `20` and if you need to access the parent's `num` value, you have to do:

```
int parentNum = super.num;
```